# React Swiper 6.8.4 only Shows Slides when resizing window or applying Filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, swiper.js

I am pretty new to coding and react and I am having an issue with Swiper 6.8.4 in my React app since i added a FilterMethod.
My idea was to have a Slider with some Projects/Images as Slides in it, and be able to filter these Slide by a multiple checkbox filter. So far everything is working fine. I am able to check multiple checkboxes and projects are filtered correctly, But i think there is a problem when initialising swiper: Every time i reload the page Swiper doesnt show any slides until i resize the page or check some filter checkboxes.

Here is my Code:
Please can somebody help me!

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import allData from '../allData';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay,Navigation, Pagination, Controller, Thumbs } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import './styles.css';

SwiperCore.use([Autoplay,Navigation, Pagination, Controller, Thumbs]);

const project = [
  { type: "Web" },
  { type: "3D" },
  { type: "Photography" },
  { type: "Print" },
  { type: "Practice" }

];

export default function App() {
  const [type, setType] = useState([]);
  const [filteredType, setFilteredType] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setType([...type, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      setType(type.filter(id => id !== e.target.value));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (type.length === 0) {
      setFilteredType(allData);
    } else {
      setFilteredType(
        allData.filter(project =>
          type.some(category => [project.type].flat().includes(category))
        )
      );
    }
  }, [type]);
  const [show, toggleShow] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div>

<Swiper 

        slidesPerView={'auto'} 
        onSlideChange={() => toggleShow(!true)}
        loop={false} 
        centeredSlides={true} 
        direction={'horizontal'}
        spaceBetween={100}
        slideToClickedSlide={true}
        pagination={{
          "type": "fraction"
        }} 
        className="mySwiper">

      {filteredType.map((project, index) => (
        <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide">
        <img className="img-slide" src={project.image} alt=""/>
        <div className="project-info">
        {show && <div className="info" key={project.id}>{project.info}</div>}

        <div className="text">{project.id} / {project.title}</div>
        </div>

        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
      </Swiper>

      <div className="filterbox">
          {project.map(project => (
            <label className={`tag${project.type}`}>  
              <input
                name="type"
                type="checkbox"
                key={project.id}
                value={project.type}
                onChange={handleChange}> 
              </input>
              <span 
                className="tags">{project.type}
              </span> 
            </label>

          ))}
        </div>
        <button  className="info-button" onClick={() => toggleShow(!show)}>Info</button>    
        
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet..

Answer (score 1):

This might help

`onInit={() => if (typeof window !== 'undefined') window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))}`